# Open CSV to export resultset to string type

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

I want to export the result set of the SQL query to a CSV file. I am using opencsv to export to CSV file. I am using below code to achieve it.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new fileWriter "testFile.csv"), '|',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
writer.writeAll(rs, true);
```

But the problem I face is, it automatically exports to the datatype of the database column which is from resultset.

Example: if I a column with datatype as float in datatype in CSV file I see as 100.00 and for another column I see value as 2.041928E+8 for 204192800.

But I want to CSV file to export to string type. The value as it as in the database.

How can I export the resulttype to CSV file with string datatype using opencsv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Another solution is, 
create your custom ResultSet Wrapper with your real resultset (source) and call

Also, you can create your custom ResultSetMetaData Wrapper to response ColumnType has String.

```
    writer.writeAll(new MyResultSet(rs), true);

//Wrapper class

public class MyResultSet implements Resultset{

 public MyResultSet(Resultset source, Map<String, NumberFormat > formatters){
//setting constructor properties and you can read here SQL resultset Metadata to complete    formatters
}

 //.... you will implement all sql.Resultset methods

  //example to implements

 public String getString(String columnName){
    return formatters.get(columnName).format(source.getInt(columnName));
  }

 public ResultSetMetaData getMetaData(){
   return new MyResultSetMetaData(source);
 }

} 

}
//
   public MyResultSetMetaData implements ResultSetMetaData{
 //will implement all ResultSetMetaData methods,

   //replace Numeric to String the column Type, then the value has retrieved by getString(column)
       public int getColumnType(int columnIndex){
  return Types.VARCHAR;
```

}

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your SQl has String example,

example with oracle:

```
  select num||'',to_char(num2) from xxx
```

or use Sql number formatter, and the resultset response with String value and not Number Values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is

```
writer.setResultService(new MyResultSetSevice());
writer.writeAll(rs, true);
```

and create a class

```
  //http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html
  public class MyResultSetSevice implements ResultSetHelper{


  public String[] getColumnValues(ResultSet rs) 
  {
      return formattedColumnValues;
  }

  String[]  getColumnValues(ResultSet rs, boolean trim) {
   return formattedColumnValues;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to explicitly write each line. It's a fairly simple method and has the advantage that you can use the "applyQuotesToAll" parameter to get CSVWriter to only quote values which need quotes, rather than everything or nothing.

```
public static void toCSV(ResultSet rs, OutputStream os)
        throws SQLException, IOException {
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

    ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
    String[] column = new String[columnCount];
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        column[i-1] = metadata.getColumnName(i);
    }
    csvWriter.writeNext(column, false);

    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            column[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
        }
        csvWriter.writeNext(column, false);
    }

    csvWriter.close();
}
```